# How to use a Global Variable in Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs, integration-testing

I've got my Yarn `package.json` set up like this, where I create a global variable called `localPath`.

```
{
  "jest": {
    "globals": {
      "localPath": "Users/alex/Git/mytodolist"
    }
  }
}
```

Then, in one of my spec tests, I run

```
console.log(localPath)
```

but get this error.

```
ReferenceError: localPath is not defined

      5 | 
    > 6 |   console.log(localPath)
```

Does anyone know how to call the global variable you set up? I can only find articles on creating the variable, but not on how to call it.

Source: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#globals-object

Edit: Thanks to @slideshowp2 for the correct answer below. Turns out I didn't need to use a global variable in the end, as you can dynamically grab the execution path at run time. However, this will certainly be useful in the future.

```js
beforeAll(async () => {
  await page.goto('file:///'+process.cwd()+'/index.html')
})
```

Comment: Did you try the same in `jest.config.js`?

Comment: Could you try `global.localPath` in your test?

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't work. Gives the same error.

Comment: What you have above is supposed to work just fine, are you sure you don't have any other jest config overriding what is in the `package.json`? And how are you running the test spec?

Comment: The above snippet is the extent of my `package.json`. I am running the test with `yarn jest test`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should work. Here is a minimal working example:

`./src/index.js`:

```js
export function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
```

`./src/__tests__/index.spec.js`:

```js
import { sum } from "../";

it("should sum", () => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  console.log("localPath: ", localPath);
  const actualValue = sum(1, 2);
  expect(actualValue).toBe(3);
});
```

`jest.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  preset: "ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts",
  testEnvironment: "node",
  coverageReporters: ["json", "text", "lcov", "clover"],
  testMatch: ["**/__tests__/**/*.[jt]s?(x)", "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[jt]s?(x)"],
  globals: {
    localPath: "Users/alex/Git/mytodolist"
  }
};
```

Unit test result:

```sh
 PASS  src/__tests__/index.spec.js
  ✓ should sum (4ms)

  console.log src/__tests__/index.spec.js:5
    localPath:  Users/alex/Git/mytodolist

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.233s
Ran all test suites.
```

As you can see, the value of global variable `localPath` has been set. Please print the `global` object and check in your tests.

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-feistel-byfcc

Comment: hey go through the link may help you